# How to determine if set of linear equations (inequalities) will be a closed shape in 3D and more

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, linear-algebra

I have a set of inequalities in more than three dimensions. The problem is defined by Ax < b (A is matrix, x is a vector of variables to be solved for b scalar vector).
Is there any algorithm to test if the these equations has close sphere or not using Matlab or python.

for illustration

```
X1  >0
X2  >0   
X1  <2
X2  <3
```

This set of equations form a closed shape.
I am trying to apply the same idea in higher dimensions

Comment: The closure has nothing to do with the implementation language; it's pure linear algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are algorithms to determine closure of a given set of continuous curves.  Treat this as a graph problem.  For the given 2-dimensional problem:

- Solve all equation pairs to determine the graph nodes.  Each intersection point is a node.
- Each pair of nodes on any given line defines an edge.
- Define a graph of these nodes and edges.  Use the methods included with any graph package (your choice; I use `networkx` in Python) to find any loops in the graph.  Each loop defines an enclosed space.

For a space of larger dimensions, you need to scale up the nodes (N-1 dimensions) and corresponding connectivity accordingly.

For the given case, you will have an edge list something like

```
X1_0    A B
X2_0    Z C
X1_2    B D
X2_3    D C
```

... and the loop algorithm will find the cycle A-B-D-C

Is that enough of a start?

Comment: When you say "solve equation pairs" and "each intersection point" doesn't that mean you are restricting to 2d? If so perhaps your answer should mention that explicitly.